# Creating python tests for api gateway endpoints

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, certificate, boto3, aws-api-gateway

I am looking into ways to automate the testing of api gateway endpoints using python.
We have a custom domain name associated with it.

This is the code I have run:

```
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
import boto3

api_ep = "<custom domain>.com"

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

auth = AWSRequestsAuth( aws_access_key = credentials.access_key,
                        aws_secret_access_key = credentials.secret_key,
                        aws_host = api_ep,
                        aws_region = "<region>",
                        aws_service = "execute-api")

response = requests.get("https://" + api_ep + "/health", auth=auth)


print(response.content)
```

I am getting multiple [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate.

When using the api gateway domain name it returns the correct response (403).

I was trying to invoke the api gateway using a python script in order to create a set of tests, but I am failing somewhere when it comes to the authentication.

Comment: Try to change the URL to HTTP instead of HTTPS

Comment: But the api endpoint is https, that doesn't make sense